# Place text on top of image at specific coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an image on which I need to put text at different places (through user input).

If I right click on the image, an input field pops up - whatever I type onto the field should be placed on exactly the same position where I right-clicked. I am able to get the x and y coordinates as I right click, but not sure how to place the text (sensor id in my case) at those coordinates.

(I use context menu for the right click functions)

Code:

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Test</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.contextMenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="css/jquery.contextMenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"    />

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready( function() {

        // Show menu when #myDiv is clicked
        $("#myDiv").contextMenu({
            menu: 'myMenu'
        },
            function(action, el, pos) {

            var name=prompt("Sensor Id ","Enter Id here");

            if (name!=null){


            alert(
                'Sensor: ' + name + 'Action: ' + action + '\n\n' +
                'Element ID: ' + $(el).attr('id') + '\n\n' + 
                'X: ' + pos.x + '  Y: ' + pos.y + ' (relative to element)\n\n' + 
                'X: ' + pos.docX + '  Y: ' + pos.docY+ ' (relative to document)'
                );


            }   

        });

    });

</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="myDiv">
    Right click to add
     <div id='cid' class='container' style="height: 100%">
    <img src="./3.jpg">
    </div>
</div>

<ul id="myMenu" class="contextMenu">
    <li class="edit"><a href="#edit">Place</a></li>
</ul>
```

In the code above, I just show the x and y coordinates - should be able to translate the coordinates + sensor id to a text(sensor id) at those coordinates.

How can I do that?

Comment: Why is this tagged php?

Comment: Create a jsfiddle with your code, so we can test it.